# TypeScript Array Initialisers with Object Initialisers

Tags: arrays, typescript

Is there any reason why the following code blocks consisting of initialisers are legal syntax in TypeScript 1.8:

```
class A
{
    public textField: string;
}

var instanceOfClass = new A
{
    textField = "HELLO WORLD"
};

var arrayCollection = new A[]
{
    new A(), new A()
};
```

...but the following code block is not?

```
var arrayCollection = new A[]
{
    new A
    {
        textField = "HELLO"
    },
    new A
    {
        textField = "WORLD"
    }
};
```

It seems odd that TypeScript will allow you initialise arrays and objects, but you otherwise can't nest object initialisers within an array initialiser.

Comment: "',' expected" around the first curly brace for each object initialised within the array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid typescript syntax:

```
class A {
    public textField: string;
}

var instanceOfClass = new A {
    textField = "HELLO WORLD"
};
```

The compiler complains:

> Cannot find name 'textField'

If you want to set a member value when instantiating then just pass it as a constructor parameter:

```
class A {
    public textField: string;

    constructor(textField: string) {
        this.textField = textField;
    }
}

var instanceOfClass = new A("HELLO WORLD");
```

Or the short version:

```
class A {
    constructor(public textField: string) {
        this.textField = textField;
    }
}
```